# Integrate C++ on webOS project

Tags: node.js, webos, lg, node.js-addon

I'm developing a project for webOS 3.0 and I want to know if it's possible to integrate a C++ lib binary on a webOS aplication. I am tying to use nodejs [addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and require the `addon.node` file into a `JSservice` like a module, but, according to [this](https://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/js-services/using-nodejs-module/) official LG developer it's not possible to integrate addons including C/C++ on webOS 3.0:

> You cannot use modules including C/C++ addons. You must use modules implemented with JavaScript only.

I also tried using [emscripten](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/index.html). This approach is not very convenient because it requires manually keeping track of all exported methods. As this project is maintained for several platforms and the code is already quite large, this becomes a hassle. The maintenance overhead would grow.

The question is whether there are any other ways of integrating C++ on webOS 3.0. Neither of the approaches I found seem ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly no.

WebOS on Palm supported C++ modules via their Plug-In Development Kit (PDK).
Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, it's not supported on LG TVs.